# ¿Como comparar un Json Array con una cadena de texto?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

como puedo comparar una cadena de texto con el contenido que tiene el Json array, el server me devuelve esto :

```
[{"url_tecnica":"prueba.pdf"},{"url_tecnica":"prueba2.pdf"}]
```

y necesito comparar que si el nombre **prueba.pdf** se encuentra ya dentro del arreglo, dejo el codigo de lo que llevo

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Url",
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    },
    success: function (result) {
        var cells =[];
        var cont = 0;
        var rows = result;
        for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
        {
        if("prueba.pdf" == rows[i]){                                        
        }
```

estoy algo perdido con esto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que haces esta bien, pero te falta convertir la respuesta en un json y acceder a la propiedad del objeto, que es `url_tecnica`

```js
var result = '[{"url_tecnica":"prueba.pdf"},{"url_tecnica":"prueba2.pdf"}]';
var respuesta = JSON.parse(result);
respuesta.forEach(function(url) {
    if (url.url_tecnica === "prueba.pdf") {
        console.log("existe");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias opciones, podrías utilizar el método `filter` para obtener un nuevo arreglo con los elementos que cumplan tu condición, por ejemplo, un nuevo arreglo que tenga todos los objetos con la propiedad `url_tecnica` con el valor `prueba.pdf`

```
const respuesta = [{"url_tecnica":"prueba.pdf"},{"url_tecnica":"prueba2.pdf"}]
const filtrado = respuesta.filter(elemento => elemento.url_tecnica === 'prueba.pdf').length
console.log(filtrado) // 1
if (filtrado === 0) {
  // no hay elementos
} else {
  // hay elementos
}
```

Podrías utilizar el método `find` para obtener el objeto que cumpla con la condición

```
const respuesta = [{"url_tecnica":"prueba.pdf"},{"url_tecnica":"prueba2.pdf"}]
const filtrado = respuesta.find(elemento => elemento.url_tecnica === 'prueba.pdf')
console.log(filtrado) // {"url_tecnica":"prueba.pdf"}
if (filtrado === undefined) {
  // no hay elementos
} else {
  // hay elementos
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia tu if para que tome el atributo que necesitas:

```
if(rows[i].url_tecnica == "prueba.pdf"){
  //tu codigo a implementar
}
```